# How does adding o(h) make a statement more precise?

Tags: limits, functions, poisson-process

From the *Introduction to Probability Models 12th Edition* by Sheldon M Ross, there exists a paragraph within *Section 5.3.2 - Definition of the Poisson Process*

> The $o(h)$ notation can be used to make statements more precise. For instance, if
> $X$ is continuous with density $f$ and failure rate function $\lambda(t)$, then the approximate statements
> $$ P(t <X <t +h) \approx f (t)h$$
> $$ P(t <X <t +h | X>t) ≈ \lambda (t) h$$
> can be precisely expressed as
> $$P(t <X <t +h) = f (t)h+o(h)$$
> $$P(t <X <t +h|X>t) = \lambda(t)h+o(h)$$

How does this make it more precise, I understand $o(h)$ is just a placeholder for any function such that

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 0$$

However, how does this make the actual expression more precise? Isn't it still the same equation as before?

Comment: "$f(h)=g(h)+o(h)$ when $h\to 0$" is more precise than "$f(h)\approx g(h)$ when $h$ close to $0$" because the latter is *totally* imprecise. What information do you get from the latter about *how* close $f(x)$ is to $g(x)$? How close is "approximately equal"? Does it get better as $h$ gets smaller? The former gives you that information. For example, $f(h)\equiv 0$ and $g(h)\equiv 10^{-100}$ (probably) satisfies the latter but not the former. $f(h)\equiv 0$ and $g(h)=\sqrt{h}$ (probably) satisfies the latter but not the former.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for the clarification. However, why is it $o(h)$? Is the reason because the error in calculating the area depends on the width of interval taken?

Comment: Look up asymptotics, you'll find the answer to all your questions

Comment: You asked a general question - why is $f(h)=g(h)+o(h)$ more precise than $f(h)\approx g(x)$. Why is the "error term" precisely $o(h)$? This should follow from whatever matter you are studying. The error term in some applications can be $o(h)$ or $o(h^2)$ or $o(h^{42})$ or $o(\log h)$ etc. In your particular application it should follow from the general properties of (Lebesgue or Riemann) integral. For every continuous function $f$ around $a\in\mathbb R$ it is true that $\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx=hf(a)+o(h)$ - take it as a Mathematical Analysis challenge to prove!

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 common ways to make statements Precise.

(1) $P \approx 1000$ is not Precise. Is $P=1012$ ok ? Is $P=1001$ ok ? Maybe it means $P=1000.1$ ? Maybe it is means more strictly $P=1000.0001$ ?
We can make it Precise by stating the bounds :
$P = 1000 (+|-) 0.01 $

This means :
$1000 -0.01 \le P \le 1000 + 0.01 $

(2) $P(x) \approx 2x^3$ is not Precise. What term is missing ? What comparisons can be made with other related values ? How close is the equality ? How can we use it in other Equations ?

We can make it Precise by stating the including the missing term :
(2A) $P(x)=2x^3+o(x^2)$

In context, it means :
$P(x)=2x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

When required, we may try to evaluate $a,b,c$.

(2B) $P(x)=2x^3+o(x)$

This may mean :
$P(x)=2x^3+ax+b$

When required, we may try to compare with $Q(x)=2x^3+\sqrt x$.

(2C) $P(x)=2x^3+o(1)$

This means :
$P(x)=2x^3+a$

When required, we can take Derivative and eliminate the Constant.

(2D) $P(x)=2x^3+o(\sqrt x)$

Meaning :
$P(x)=2x^3+a\sqrt x$

When required, we can use this in $P(x)-Q(x)$ & manipulate it.

All these are $P(x) \approx 2x^3$ but with lot of variety.

We are unable to use $P(x) \approx 2x^3$ in such ways because that is not Precise.

Comment: Your explanation of the $o(\cdot)$ notation goes the other way by being ***too*** precise. For example, $P(x)=2x^3+o(1)$ does not mean $P(x)=2x^3+a$ for some constant $a$, it instead means $|P(x)-2x^3| \le a$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: That was the reason I said "**In context**, it means ...." , & "This **may** mean" , @LeeMosher , where we may be using Polynomials & there is nothing "between" $1$ & $x$ . It is a simplification to Explain the Point. No matter what Example I give , I could make some Exception !

Comment: (-1) two issues. (1) $o(g(x)) \implies \lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ which seems to be wrongly expressed in this answer. (2) The actual answer doesn't explain anything as to why $o(h)$ makes it more precise

Comment: Your Post is incorrect when you say "o(h) is is place holder for the limit [...]" & naturally your Previous Comment is incorrect too. You might want to clear your misconceptions [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis ]] Check the Comment by "user Lee Mosher" who says that I am going "too Precise" ! Check whether that comment matches your thinking ! @SafdarFaisal

Comment: The Answer Explains that out of all Possible missing terms, only "the linear term" is the missing term here which makes it more Precise than claiming "it is approximate" or "some term is missing".